# Javascript - passing a variable to session.getAttribute

Tags: javascript, session, variables

I have a Java servlet that successfully sets a bunch of session variables, Say:

SessionVar1
SessionVar2
SessionVar3

Now, in Java Script, I can read and print the session variables using code similar to the following:

```
var name = '<%= session.getAttribute( "SessionVar1" ) %>';      
var name = '<%= session.getAttribute( "SessionVar2" ) %>';      
var name = '<%= session.getAttribute( "SessionVar3" ) %>';
```

Then I call document.write printing name1,name2 and name3.

Again, this works without a problem. However, I don't have 3 session variables but 100.
I do not want to write 100 calls to session.getAttribute so I wanted to use a "FOR" loop
and append the loop counter to the name of the session variable to retrieve. Something along the lines of:

```
int i=100;
for (i=1; i<=100; i++)
{
   var VariableName = "SessionVar" + i;
   var name = '<%= session.getAttribute( VariableName ) %>';      
   document.write(name);
}
```

I tried many combination and I'm unable to pass a parameter to session.getAttribute. I understand that Javascript parameters do not exist in the context of the server, but
I was wondering if there is any way to avoid having to call session.getAttribute 100 times.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Guy

Answer (score 1):

Of course not--the scriptlet (boooo) is run before the client has a chance to run any JavaScript.

The canonical solution is to generate the JS in Java (preferably using tags), *very* roughly:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { %>
    var name<%= i %> = '<%= session.getAttribute("SessionVar" + i) %>';
<% } %>
```

With the caveat that (a) ew, and (b) you should JavaScript-escape the attribute to be safe.

This still calls `getAttribute` 100 times--you need 100 session variables (already starting to be a code smell), you call it 100 times. Your other option is to put this all into an array, because `nameNNN` is a bit weird too--collections exist for a reason.

Comment: +1: I saw production code like this way back in 2001... didn't know that people still think this way